# Jquery tabs with static and ajax content?

Tags: jquery

I have a page that is using jQuery tabs. Each tab has a static form. Until here there is no problem...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs_1_10").tabs( {
    "show": function(event, ui) { }
    } );
} );
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="tabs_1_10">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1_11">VAT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1_24">VAT - SELL</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1_11"><?php separator_1_11(); ?></div>
<div id="tabs-1_24"><?php separator_1_24(); ?></div>
</div>
```

PHP functions

```
function separator_1_11() {
    ...
    ajax_function_1_11();
    ...
}
function separator_1_24() {
    ...
    ajax_function_1_24();
    ...
}
```

separator_1_11() and separator_1_24() are functions that draw the forms and at the end call an ajax javascript function that populate the fields in the form with values from database. All working until now.

My problem is that I need to call that ajax javascript function and only that function each time I select another tab because that values could be changed and I don´t want to request all form.

I think I should be using onClick like this

```
<a href="#tabs-1_11" onClick="ajax_function_1_12();">

<a href="#tabs-1_11" onClick="ajax_function_1_24();">
```

I'm just not sure if this should work, bacause for me it don't work. Any comment??